# Keeps connecting to wrong router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Because the WiFi connection is quite bad in some places in my home, we decided to put an extra router in the network. It seemed to work, but we discovered that it is constantly connecting to the same router, whether this one has the best signal or not. With some help from the internet, here's what we did to set-up the network:

- The routers are connected LAN-to-LAN
- The second router's IP is one higher than the original. So 192.168.178.2 where primary is 192.168.178.1
- The channel's are not the same
- The SSIDs of the four networks are the same (two routers, 2.4GHz and 5GHz)

The second router is an Edimax and in the set-up we can chose one of two options: full router and a WAN-to-LAN or access-point with LAN-to-LAN. We chose the latter because WAN-to-LAN creates a subnetwork, right?

According to the internet, we should also disable DHCP on the second router, but there is no option to do this. Only when set-up as a router instead of access-point.

As you can see on the screenshot below, it keeps connecting to the router with the weakest signal even though I am standing next to the primary router.

[image: Router diagnosis]

How do I set-up the routers in a way that my devices connect to the one with the best signal?

Comment: Devices typically have a preference list, and will only "roam" or select an item lower on a preference list if the defined difference in signal strength is met. Look for a setting on the device wireless hardware settings called "roaming aggressiveness". Only certain devices will support this, and other devices may call it by a different name.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally up to your client devices to decide which AP to join, when more than one AP is publishing the same network name. If your client devices aren't smart enough to make good choices, you'll have to give each AP a different network name (SSID) and manually switch your client device from one to another when you move to different parts of your home.

There are some AP products that try to second-guess the clients and trick/force them to switch which AP they're joined to, but that's generally a feature of enterprise-class products, not consumer products.